# read two integers from buffer in python

Tags: python, buffer

I have two int16 values adjacent in a numpy array which are supposed to represent a timestamp.

```
[-1920 -1320]
```

How can I transfrom those into the actual timetamp?

I had a similar problem converting a single 64bit integer before and used

```
np.frombuffer()
```

but now my value consists of two integers. How do I combine these and read out the associated iformation?

Comment: There are lots of ways to combine two 16-bit words of information, so it's hard to tell which one you need. What timestamp is `[-1920 -1320]` supposed to convert into?

Comment: its supposed to represent a 32bit counter

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer my question. What is the exact value that the 32bit counter will contain? I'm looking for a value such as `4208523392`.

Comment: the only information I got is that its a 32bit timestamp in ms

Comment: How did that data get into your Numpy array? Is it from a file?

Comment: it was written by a sensor to hdf5 files and I use h5py to access them

Comment: Do you know anything about what the timestamps are supposed to represent? I tried four different ways to turn these numbers into timestamps and they occur in the years 2103, 2102, 2085, and 2038. Would any of those make sense for your data? Or do you think the timestamps should be in the near past / present / near future?

Comment: thank you so much for your effort. I accomplished similar results will lead me to the assumption that the numbers do not represent timestamps although the should. In fact, they should point to today

Comment: Do you have *any* more info about this mysterious sensor? Without some solid info, your question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: Do you have more than this one timestamp? It would help to have several with a known offset.

Comment: -1720 -1292
-476 -744
-1752 -1404
-492 -752
-1824 -1360
 line separated which should result in a current date in ms

Answer (score 0):

Time stamp is vague so I am unsure what you want there, you need to specify the format. That being said you can covert those 16-bit numbers into one large 32-bit number by doing the following:

```
nums = [-1920, -1320]
bits_16 = 0xffff

# 2's compiliments
r = [bin(y & bits_16)[2:] if y < 0 else f'{y:016b}' for y in nums]

# Condense all the 2's into one string and convert to int
int_value = int(''.join(r), 2)
print(r)
print(int_value)
```

Output:

```
['1111100010000000', '1111101011011000']
4169202392 # The signed version (2's compliment) would be -125764904
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys. The only information I have is 'supports an independent 32-bit timestamp for each frame'

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to answer questions where we don't have all the necessary info. BTW, there are better ways to make bitstrings from unsigned numbers than messing about with `bin`, eg `format(y, '016b')`, and in Python 3.6+ it's even more compact (and faster): `f'{y:016b}'`

Comment: @PM2Ring actually if you look they are signed numbers. Meaning string formatting doesnt work. That crossed my mind but you should probably look close before trying to offer an invalid solution :). My solution is not to solve to full question but to solve part of it. I provided a way to combine two 16-bit numbers (which is half of the problem statement).

Comment: I'm not offering a solution to the OP's question! Of course I can see that the data is signed (although I suspect that it shouldn't be, that's a separate issue). I was simply telling *you* about better ways to convert unsigned numbers to bits than using `bin` etc. I assumed that I didn't need to explain to you that signed numbers need special handling, since your code already does that.